# How to remove "R$ " from a string to convert it to float in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to remove monetary formatting from a string like "R$ 30.00", to convert in float afterward. I'm new to BigQuery and I'm trying regexp.replace, but it's not working, it doesn't replace anything.

SELECT
REGEXP_REPLACE(string, r"R$ ", "") as string

Comment: **select  cast(replace("$R 30.01", "$R", "") as float64) as float_value**

Comment: REPLACE function: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#replace

Answer (score 0):

Regular Expressions (RegEx or RegExp) are a powerful string manipulation tool. A good resources is https://regex101.com/

Instead of replacing characters with blanks, you could just extract the digits and cast that as a float. This will avoid any spaces or other characters as well. Try this out and you can replace 'R$ 30.00' with any string of dollar values.

```
SELECT CAST(REGEXP_EXTRACT('R$ 30.00', r'\d+\.\d*') AS FLOAT64)
```

Here's the [BigQuery function documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#regexp_extract) on the `REGEXP_EXTRACT` function. The first parameter in the function is the field (or expression) you want to evaluate. The second parameter is the Regular Expression to extract the information out of the string. The `r` lets BigQuery know that I want it to take the string literally (because backslashes `\` are seen as "escape characters" in normal strings. Then the `\d+` says to find at least 1+ digit characters. Then it will look for a `.` period. Then `\d*` will look for 0 or more digits after the period.

Comment: Thanks for the complete and helpful reply!
Since then I've researched and got it to work with replace, although it caused me to have an empty string that I had to make null after.
I forgot to mention my strings are like: "R$ 30.000,50" where numbers after ',' are decimals.
I tried to make extract work without bringing '.' but it doesn't brind the numbers before '.' also. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you saying your values are using Full Stop (or decimal) separator notation? Meaning 30.00,50 would be 30,000.50 in comma notation or (30000.50 as a float)?

Comment: The values have inverted roles for , and . in english formatting.
So 30.000,50 should be converted to 30,000.50, or 30000.50 as float.

This expression REGEXP_EXTRACT('R$ 30.00', r'\d+\.\d*') on "30,000.50"
would return "000.50"